# Google report api not chronological

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-reporting-api

I use this code in my object to get Google Analytics API data

```
$this->end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'));
$this->start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-27 days', strtotime($this->end_date)));

$this->ga->requestReportData(xxxx,array('date'), array('sessions'), null, '', $this->start_date, $this->end_date);

foreach($this->ga->getResults() as $result) {
  $this->date = $result->getDate();
  $this->visits = $result->getSessions();

  $this->date = strtotime($this->date);
  $this->date = date("d-m-Y", $this->date);
  $i++;

  $this->dateArray .= "{date: '". $this->date ."', visits: ". $this->visits . $i ."},";

}

$this->dateArray =  substr($this->dateArray, 0, -1);
```

For some reason some dates are not in order, what am I doing wrong or is this normal and is there a different type of fix for it?

This is my output for $this->ga->getResults()

```
Array ( [20180117] => 0 [20180118] => 0 [20180119] => 0 [20180120] => 0 [20180121] => 0 [20180122] => 0 [20180124] => 0 [20180125] => 0 [20180127] => 0 [20180128] => 0 [20180129] => 0 [20180131] => 0 [20180202] => 0 [20180204] => 0 [20180207] => 0 [20180208] => 0 [20180209] => 0 [20180210] => 0 [20180212] => 0 [20180126] => 1 [20180201] => 1 [20180203] => 1 [20180205] => 1 [20180211] => 1 [20180123] => 3 [20180206] => 5 [20180213] => 5 [20180130] => 31 )
```

Comment: Please print your output.

Comment: this is my output Array ( [20180117] => 0 [20180118] => 0 [20180119] => 0 [20180120] => 0 [20180121] => 0 [20180122] => 0 [20180124] => 0 [20180125] => 0 [20180127] => 0 [20180128] => 0 [20180129] => 0 [20180131] => 0 [20180202] => 0 [20180204] => 0 [20180207] => 0 [20180208] => 0 [20180209] => 0 [20180210] => 0 [20180212] => 0 [20180126] => 1 [20180201] => 1 [20180203] => 1 [20180205] => 1 [20180211] => 1 [20180123] => 3 [20180206] => 5 [20180213] => 5 [20180130] => 31 )

Comment: Where is `$i` being initialized and what's it set to? What about the rest of the class?

Comment: $i is not relevant its just for debugging, i had the same problem before introducing $i

Comment: The `$this->ga->getResults()` isn't ordered to begin with, so unless you sort it they won't be in order. Towards the end of the array the timestamps go from ....`20180210`, `20180212` back down to `20180126` then jumps forward in time again at `20180201`, `20180203`, `20180205` then starts back up again at `20180211` where it was skipped over before, then back down to `20180123`, and so on. Assuming the `getResults` method is part of Google's API, the data you're feeding into it must be the problem.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your output from `$this->ga->getResults()`. If those are timestamps, they're from the 1970's, but you appear to be running a report of the last 27 days. Ex: `20180117` is 08/22/1970 @ 1:35pm (UTC). Also, you've stated that `$this->ga->getResults()` is an array, but you're using it like an object in the foreach loop, such as `$result->getDate();`. It seems like you're leaving out some important info. Please include a link to the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics reporting API doesn't guarantee results are sorted unless you specifically use the [`sort` operator](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#sort).

Try adding `sort=ga:date` to your request and that should work.

Alternatively, write your code to assume that the data is unsorted, and handle the sorting yourself.